# How to Set FormAuthenticator Attributes

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I need to set landingPage Attribute Of  Form Authenticator. I saw that The Form Authenticator Valve supports the configuration attributes like landingPage.

http://www.ide.iitkgp.ernet.in/docs/config/valve.html#Form_Authenticator_Valve

I tried to set it like

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.CustomFormAuthenticator856" landingPage="/Landingpage.do"/>
```

but after adding this server itself was not working properly. so how to specify the attribute in server.xml .

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have "org.apache.catalina.authenticator.**CustomFormAuthenticator856**" as *className*? It's not in the Tomcat-Docs. The correct value for *FormAuthenticator* is "org.apache.catalina.authenticator.**FormAuthenticator**".
I also think you don't need the leading "/" for *landingPage*.

So your valve tag should be:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator" landingPage="Landingpage.do"/>
```